# How to use a jQuery plugin inside Vue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, webpack, vue.js

I'm building a web application inside VueJS but I encounter a problem. I want to use a jQuery extension (cropit to be specific) but I don't know how to instantiate/require/import it the right way without getting errors.

I'm using de official CLI tool and de webpack template for my App.

I included jQuery like this in my main.js file:

```
import jQuery from 'jQuery'
window.jQuery = jQuery
```

Now I'm building an image editor component where I want to instantiate crept like this:

```
export default {
  ready () {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
      $('#image-cropper-wrapper-element').cropit({ /* options */ })
    })
  },
 }
```

But I keep getting errors...Now my question is how to properly instantiate jQuery and plugins via NPM/Webpack/Vue?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Option #1: Use ProvidePlugin**

Add the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery) to the plugins array in both `build/webpack.dev.conf.js` and `build/webpack.prod.conf.js` so that jQuery becomes globally available to all your modules:

```
plugins: [

  // ...

  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
]
```

**Option #2: Use Expose Loader module for webpack**

As @TremendusApps suggests in his answer, add the [Expose Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader) package:

```
npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

Use in your entry point `main.js` like this:

```
import 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery'

// ...
```

Comment: Try putting in something else into the plugin below the jquery...like `'test': require('../src/test')` and see if you get test in all your components. I did this as well and it works.

Answer (score 15):

First install jquery  using npm,

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Add in *app.js* before require('/[path_to]/main.js');

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
var $ = global.jQuery;
window.$ = $;
```

Answer (score 14):

import jquery within <script> tag in your vue file.

I think this is the easiest way.

For example,

```
<script>
import $ from "jquery";

export default {
    name: 'welcome',
    mounted: function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('.logo').css('opacity', 0);   
        }, 1000);
    } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Suppose you have Vue project created with vue-cli (e.g. vue init webpack my-project).
Go to project dir and run

`npm install jquery --save`

Open file `build/webpack.base.conf.js` and add `plugins`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
  ...
}
```

Also at top of file add:

`const webpack = require('webpack')`

If you are using ESLint, open `.eslintrc.js` and add next globals: {

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    "$": true,
    "jQuery": true
  },
  ...
```

Now you are ready to go. Use $ anywhere in your js.

**NOTE** You don't need to include expose loader or any other stuff to use this.

*Originally from https://maketips.net/tip/223/how-to-include-jquery-into-vuejs*

Answer (score 6):

You need to use either the `globals` loader or `expose` loader to ensure that webpack includes the jQuery lib in your source code output and so that it doesn't throw errors when your use $ in your components.

```
// example with expose loader:
npm i --save-dev expose-loader

// somewhere, import (require) this jquery, but pipe it through the expose loader
require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery')
```

If you prefer, you can import (require) it directly within your webpack config as a point of entry, so I understand, but I don't have an example of this to hand

Alternatively, you can use the globals loader like this: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/globals-loader

Answer (score 5):

There's a much, much easier way. Do this:

```
MyComponent.vue

<template>
  stuff here
</template>
<script>
  import $ from 'jquery';
  import 'selectize';

  $(function() {
      // use jquery
      $('body').css('background-color', 'orange');

      // use selectize, s jquery plugin
      $('#myselect').selectize( options go here );
  });

</script>
```

Make sure JQuery is installed first with `npm install jquery`. Do the same with your plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I use it like this:

```
import jQuery from 'jQuery'

ready: function() {
    var self = this;
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
      self.$refs.thisherechart.drawChart();
    })
  },
```

Comment: But then how do you add a plugin to jQuery? Like I intend to do.

Comment: To include a plugin use require after the jquery import above. 
`require("<jquery-plugin-name>")`
then call it like normal in the code
`jQuery(window).<pluginmethod>`

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**
We place ourselves with the terminal in the folder of our project and install JQuery through npm or yarn.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

**Step 2**
Within our file where we want to use JQuery, for example app.js (*resources/js/app.js*), in the script section we include the following code.

```
// We import JQuery
const $ = require('jquery');
// We declare it globally
window.$ = $;

// You can use it now
$('body').css('background-color', 'orange');

// Here you can add the code for different plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vue3 thats using the TypeScript version you can add it like this.

```
npm i --save jquery
npm i --save @types/jquery
```

Then in your main.ts file.

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.$ = jQuery
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your application.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  $(document).ready(() => console.log('test'))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install jquery --save`

then on your root component, place this

```
global.jQuery = require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
var $ = global.jQuery;
```

Do not forget to export it to enable you to use it with other components

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {$}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my project. I fixed it by importing a separate js file to my vue component.
I created a `const` that has methods that can use jQuery on the `main.js`.

main.js

```
export const jQueryMixin = {
    method: {
        init() {}
    }
}
```

And on my vue component, I imported and used the object I created on the `main.js`.

Home.vue

```
import { jQueryMixin } from '../../main';

export default {
    created() {
        jQueryMixin.method.init();
    }
}
```