# Vue loader - import jquery globally for all components

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am using vue-loader single file components.
When i want to use jquery in specific component i use this code:

```
import $ from 'jQuery'
```

How can import jquery globally, for all components? Just like i import vue component in main.js, for example

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
```

This apporoach hovewer cannot be used with jquery.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue

Answer (score 2):

U should use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) to make it global.

for **webpack v2**, add to webpack rule

```
{
   test: require.resolve('jquery'),
   use: [{
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: 'jQuery'
   },
   {
      loader: 'expose-loader',
               options: '$'
   }]
}
```