# What is the best way to include or initialize jQuery library in Vue project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

What is the best way to include the jQuery library in Vue project?

I'm using a vue-cli, webpack and router. I have separate components and I need to include few jQuery plugins. If I include jQuery script in index file, then I have problem to manipulate (trigger) DOM from components. So I guess it's better to include all scripts in my main.js or components?

I need to implement [Venobox](http://veno.es/venobox/) plugin. 
This is basic jQuery initialization

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.venobox').venobox(); 
});
```

In Vue i tried with

```
  mounted () {
    $('.venobox').venobox();
  }
```

Now I have problem with jQuery. '$' is not defined etc. 
What is the best practice to include external JS files in Vue project? 
Is there are ease way to initialize jQuery plugins?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery and vue should be able to work side by side on the same page no problem. If you'd like to use jQuery inside a vue component, `mounted()` looks like a good direction to do that. Can you install jQuery on the page the same way you install Vue?

Comment: Are you using plain javascript? or something like webpack?

Comment: Assuming you installed jQuery with npm, you can just import it with `import $ from "jquery";`.

Comment: @Kos, I installed jquery via NPM

Comment: @Gerard, I am using webpack

Comment: @str, Thanks, jquery is there, I got a new error 'TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_jquery___default(...)(...).venobox is not a function'. I am trying to import venobox 'import venobox from 'venobox'' but then I got error ''venobox' is defined but never used'

Comment: do this in the file you initialize vuejs :     window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

Comment: @Glavar and did you install Venobox through npm also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only this one component that uses jQuery, I'd import it exclusively inside of it and wouldn't bother with anything else. Your code was correct (initialising `venobox` inside the `mounted` lifecycle hook), but you also have to import jQuery inside your component:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export default {
  mounted () {
    $('.venobox').venobox();
  }
}
```

However, if you use jQuery inside other components as well, I suggest looking at this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653758/2803743. Pasting option 1 here in case it gets removed/changed (the use of Webpack's ProvidePlugin):

> Option #1: Use ProvidePlugin
>
> Add the ProvidePlugin to the plugins array in both build/webpack.dev.conf.js and build/webpack.prod.conf.js so that jQuery becomes globally available to all your modules:

```
plugins: [
  // ...

  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
]
```

Comment: Thanks Kano, I also put 'require('venobox')' in my main.js file and work like a charm.

Comment: Excellent! If this answer helped you, you may mark it as the correct one to help out future answer-seekers :)

Answer (score 2):

**Main js file** that will be compiled by webpack:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('venobox/venobox');

window.Vue = require('vue');

// Register your components and your global Vue instance after that
```

I suppose that you already have the dependencies installed from your `package.json` file.

You simply have to import all your dependencies before registering your components.