# How to load signalr.js in webpack inside Vue2

Tags: vue.js, webpack-2

In this way:[How to use a jQuery plugin inside Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue)
But ,Error: '$' is not defined
What do I need to do, to get signalr working using webpack? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ms-signalr-client 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms-signalr-client
for webpack 
 for loading library I use

> `import $ from 'jquery'
>   window.jQuery = $
>   require('ms-signalr-client')`