# datepicker not working for new record added to the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

```css
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script/vue")
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
   el: '#holiday-vue',
   data: {
    holidays:  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
    tableHeader: 'Local Holidays',
    holidayWarning: true,
    dateWarning: true
   },
      methods: {
      addHoliday: function () {
      this.holidays.LocalHolidays.push(this.holidays.DefaultHolidayViewModel);
    },
   });
 </script>
```

```html
<div id="holiday-vue">
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <table id="tableID">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Holiday</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody v-for="h in holidays.LocalHolidays">
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Holiday Name" required="required" v-model="h.Name" />
          </td>
          <td class="col-sm-3">
            <input id="date" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required="required" class="form-control datepicker" v-model="h.Date" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>&nbsp;<span v-on:click="addHoliday()"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Holiday</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used "push" to add a new row to the table. The new row gets added at the end of all rows but the "datepicker" doesn't work only for the new added row. for the rest of the rows, it works fine.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help you, please include the core of your code, we're only seeing at the HTML, please show some javascript

Comment: addHoliday: function () {
     this.holidays.LocalHolidays.push(this.holidays.DefaultHolidayViewModel);
    },

Comment: I don't think assign id (`<input id="date"`) is one good idea, especially within one `v-for`

Comment: @Sphinx (<input id="date")  does not work for internet explorer. I need to run the code for internet explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, I have to say mix JQuery and Vue is really not one good idea.**

**The issue:**

Vue is based on Virtual Dom, so you'd better to initialze each DatePick Dom element with `$('.datepicker').datepicker()` once Vue re-render.

In your codes, when add holidays, Vue creates one new input, but new input doesn't apply `.datepicker()`.

One quick solution based on [Vue LifeCycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), you need to hook updated/mounted to make sure all new `input.datepicker` are initialized with `.datepicker()`.  (if you remove the function=updated, you will see the issue same as yours)

You can check [How to use a jQuery plugin inside Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue) or google it, you will find some more.

PS: sorry for my bad english... :(

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#holiday-vue',
    data: {
      holidays:  {
        LocalHolidays: [{Date:'2017/01/01',Name:'A'}, {Date:'2018/01/01',Name:'B'}],
        DefaultHolidayViewModel: {Date:'2019/01/01',Name:'None'}
      },
      tableHeader: 'Local Holidays',
      holidayWarning: true,
      dateWarning: true
    },
    mounted: function() {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker()
    },
    updated: function () {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker('remove')
      $('.datepicker').datepicker()
    },    
    methods: {
      addHoliday: function () {
        this.holidays.LocalHolidays.push(this.holidays.DefaultHolidayViewModel);
        
      }
    }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="holiday-vue">
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <table id="tableID">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Holiday</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody v-for="h in holidays.LocalHolidays">
        <tr>
          <td class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Holiday Name" required="required" v-model="h.Name" />
          </td>
          <td class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" required="required" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd" v-model="h.Date" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>&nbsp;<span v-on:click="addHoliday()"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Holiday</a></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to run the code but there are two problems occurring here:

1) there are 2 calendars showing up for each date inputs

2) when new row is added, the datepicker does pop up, but when you click on a particular date, that date is not excepted as the input. Basically it doesn't take the input when you click on the date.

Comment: that was expected unless you know how bootstrap datepicker works. normally this kind of JQuery plugin will add something (like add one div with grid or table) to support calendar popup. so you need to add some codes in the hook to avoid multiple initialization and something else. for the second issue you mentioned, the root cause is date format, just adjust to `yyyy-mm-dd`, then works. anyway, it is not idea to use JQuery in vue, you will need to do something more to let JQuery and Vue working welll together.

Comment: @JayatiSomani, never use bootstrap-datepicker before. but finally found one way, remove datepickers then add them again by `$('.datepicker').datepicker('remove')`, though poor efficiency