# Daterangepicker not working on click event inside Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, daterangepicker

I'm new in JS and Vue, really struggle with this one:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cutcell/hy1L5s4z/5/)

No popup, but when I'm moving `$('.date-range-picker').daterangepicker(...)` outside Vue instance, everything is ok, picker popup are shown.

Comment: i am wondering if the class exists on the DOM when the `methods.onClick` code is evaluated, maybe you need a delegated click event, however not sure how you would implement it here.

Comment: put your codes into mounted hook like `mounted: function () {
     var vm = this;
      $('.date-range-picker').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'right'
      }, function(start, end, label) {
        vm.dateRange = start.format('DD.MM.YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('DD.MM.YYYY');
      });
    },` then you'd better check [Use JQuery in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue) and [Make VueJS and jQuery play nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240789/make-vuejs-and-jquery-play-nice), anyway, it is not recommanded to use JQuery in Vue.

Comment: like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxtf04vL/)

Comment: `mounted` solution works fine for me. Thank you [Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5665870/sphinx), save my day.

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly found workaround via `input` tag and `focus` event:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cutcell/hy1L5s4z/53/)