# bootstrap4-toggle jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my `app.js` I have

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap4-toggle'

window.$ = $
window.jQuery = $
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (bootstrap4-toggle.js:182)
    at Object../node_modules/bootstrap4-toggle/js/bootstrap4-toggle.js (app.js:1407)
```

I think the import is done before the `window.jQuery = $`, but if I move the `import 'bootstrap4-toggle'` afterwards, I still get the same issue.

What did I miss?

Comment: Are u using react or angular?

Comment: why even using jQuery?

Comment: @ProgrammerDancuk Bootstrap requires jquery.

Comment: I am using neither `react` nor `angular`

Comment: @Difster No, bootstrap's js comps that requires 'optional' jQuery

Comment: did you figured out the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`bootstrap4-toggle`** doesn't import jQuery itself explicitly, but instead relies on jQuery living globally.  So when that script is being imported, the builder doesn't know where to grab that variable from (by default). So fixing will depend on the build system you're using. Most build systems won't produce global variables by default or even allow you to write to `window`.

#### Vite Build System

If you're using **Vite**, you can install [**`@rollup/plugin-inject`**](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/inject):

```bash
$ npm i @rollup/plugin-inject -D
```

Then add the following to your `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    inject({
        // remember to add `jquery` in `dependencies` for `package.json`
        jQuery: "jquery",
        $: "jquery"
    })
  ]
})
```

At this point, you'll no longer need to even call `import 'jquery'` within your script files.  Anytime a script attempts to use `jQuery` or `$` and it's not defined locally, you'll just use the globally injected value.

**Note**: If you never use the value within a script, it won't be injected.  So if you're testing, make sure you use it at least once.

#### Webpack

If you're using webpack, use [**`ProvidePlugin`**](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery) in your webpack config like this:

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
]
```

#### JS Modules

If your build output is in JavaScript Modules, one of the benefits is that they don't have any global window pollution by default. However, if you're trying to add jQuery to the window object for standalone scripts that don't go through your build process, you'll have to assign to the window explicitly like this:

```js
Object.assign(window, { $: jQuery, jQuery })
```

#### Further Reading

- [How to use a jQuery plugin inside Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37928998/1366033)
- [How to use jQuery with Laravel and Vite](https://devdojo.com/thinkverse/how-to-use-jquery-with-laravel-and-vite)
- [How to use Bootstrap 4 and jQuery with Vite v2](https://www.mapledesign.co.uk/tech-blog/vite-bootstrap-4-jquery/)