# Using plain JS in Vue.js Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So, I want to create a navbar and rather than re-invent the wheel, I am using some public code to speed up my MVP dev.

Essentially, I am using this nav-bar code - https://codepen.io/PaulVanO/pen/GgGeyE.

But I am not sure of how I can implement jquery part within my Vue code (I have made a component, copied over html and css, now just need to integrate the jquery functionality within it.)

Here is the Jquery code I need to integrate.

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

It would be really thankful if anyone could help me accomplish with this.

Comment: Do you want to put this script inside `<script>` tag of the component?

Comment: Can you provide us with the code of the component you created?
Than I can help you to toggle the navbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a jQuery plugin inside Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your markup (html and css) as part of one component, getting the toggle to add/remove a class would be really simple, you just need to have a method toggle the active state and a data property to keep the data. An example would be better, so here it goes.
In your component object:

```
{
    data() {
        return {
            isActive: false
        }
    },

    methods: {
        toggleMenu(){
            this.isActive = !this.isActive
        }
    }
}
```

In  your markup you need this

```
<div class="button_container" id="toggle" :class="{'active': isActive}" @click="toggleMenu">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
------------------------------------
<div class="overlay" id="overlay" :class="{'open': isActive}">
<nav class="overlay-menu">
  <ul>
    <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

That should get you going, just note i used the shorthand form for [v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) and for [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

EDIT:
[Here's also a link to an updated pen with the whole example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPrELX)

Comment: Man, you are the best!! Worked like a charm