# How to connect other JavaScript file to Vue file without any error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to connect other `.js` file to my `.vue` file.

So, i use theese line of code in my `.vue` file:

```
import  jQuery from 'jquery'
import './assets/js/script'
```

But, the console in Chrome (and other browsers) say:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I don't get why is it happening because i import `jQuery` var. and i use  `jQuery().` structure in my `.js` file

UPD: Sure, i have used `npm install jquery`;
 I have also tried to use `var jQuery = require("jquery")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

As suggested  in the comments.

There are multiple ways to implement jquery into your project. For other people who come across this question I will reference a few links you can try if the above suggestion does not work.

[article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue)

[article 2](https://medium.com/code4mk-org/how-to-use-jquery-inside-vue-add-other-js-library-inside-vue-9eea8fbd0416)

Comment: please using import $ from 'jquery' change your import

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it