# Unable to call function in backend from a different project

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, vue-component

I have a vue component that is supposed to grab the user information and submit to a backend (dotnetcore) function in a different project which makes an api call to an external service. It looks kinda like this:

```html
<v-btn>
  @click="submit"
>
  Submit
</v-btn>
```

then some other stuff
then inside the script tag:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      object: {
        name: "",
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function() {
      if(object.name != "") {
        $.post('/some/path/to/controller/controller/method')
          .then(data => {
            this.object = data;
          });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried changing that path to the complete url like: `https://name:socket/path/to/method` but that hasn't helped either.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I get this in console:
`[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Vue does't have $, maybe you should import jquery first

Comment: [how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue)