# How to add script to Vue component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have html template which contain src to js scripts.
How add them to vue component?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/library/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <!-- Main Js Plugin -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.min.js'></script>
        <!-- Theme main js -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='./src/assets/js/custom.theme.js'></script
```

Comment: You can refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 3: If the script will be called around the time the component is mounted, add the script in the setup() function which is the same as the `created` hook for Vue 2.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  components: {},
  props: {},
  setup() {
    const googleSignInScript = document.createElement('script');
      googleSignInScript.setAttribute(
        'src',
        'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'
      );
      googleSignInScript.setAttribute('async', 'true');
      googleSignInScript.setAttribute('defer', 'true');
      document.head.appendChild(googleSignInScript);

    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

If the script will be used quite later, you can add it in the `onMounted` hook

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  components: {},
  props: {},
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      const googleSignInScript = document.createElement('script');
      googleSignInScript.setAttribute(
        'src',
        'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'
      );
      googleSignInScript.setAttribute('async', 'true');
      googleSignInScript.setAttribute('defer', 'true');
      document.head.appendChild(googleSignInScript);
    })
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

For Vue 2: Add the script in the `created` or `mounted` hook as suitable for your application.