# How can I reproduce this navigation with the Vuetify's component 'navigation drawer'?

Tags: css, angularjs, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify and the component `Navigation Drawer`

I'm trying to reproduce [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav) navigation.

The menu on the left is fix, the width doesn't change even if we resize the browser window.

And when we resize until the breakpoint (width still doesn't change), the menu disappear and an icon button appear, which can re-open the menu hover the content.

That is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I tried so many things and nothing works.

Any help ?

This is my code :

```
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" class="nav-container d-flex">
        <div class="options">
            <li></li> //items..
        </div>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    
      <div style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100%;" class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0">
            //content
      </div>
```

Is there a way to do it with Vuetify only ?

Answer (score 0):

I think It is CSS problem.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="left-side">
  <ul>
   <li>Black</li>
   <li>Black</li>
   <li>Black</li>
   <li>Black</li>
   <li>Black</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS style

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    position: static;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    width: 272px;
    min-width: 272px;
    max-width: 272px;
}
.container > * {
    min-width: 218px;
}
```

Comment: As you can see this case in https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav debug section.

Comment: Ok it almost worked. But I still some issues. The first one is the menu doesn't dynamically disappear, I have to press on the window to make it disappear. And the second one is, when it disappear, the content doesn't resize there's a white space(where the menu was). I edited my question so you can see my code!

Comment: Yes, you can add class when the width is some value and then should add `display: none` and `transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);`.

Comment: And then you should add animation or transition

Comment: Or you can use JQUERY such as `$mdSidenav('left').toggle();`

Comment: I'm using Vue.js

Comment: No problem, In vue.js we can use Jquery.

Comment: Or if you not want Jquery, You can use vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Can you give me an example with JQuery ($mdSidenav) inside a Vue.js component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue

Comment: You can see how to import Jquery in Vue.js

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-jquery-in-vue-component/45000

Comment: You can also see the Jquery examples in Vue component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236598/discussion-between-johnw2smith-and-harry-potter).

Comment: I think we can use slack chat box, Because Almost developers are using that.

Comment: Give me your mail address.

Comment: I have invited your slack.