# How to fix Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bootstrap') in VUE-JS 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

i am getting error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bootstrap')` while adding this file into App.vue. it's before i keep that code in index.html file where i was not getting any error but **slimscroll.min.js** and some other file code was not working. i do not know what was problem. all files was being load and has 200 status code when i checked in inspect view of Network tab. so after that i putting this all files into App.js then getting this error. I was looking this problem in everywhere but not getting any solution.
can anyone tell me why i am getting error?

```
<script >
   import   "./assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js";
   import   "./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js";
   import   "./assets/js/popper.min.js";
   import   "./assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js";
   import   "./assets/js/metisMenu.min.js";
   import   "./assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js";
   import   "./assets/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js";
   import   "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js";
   import "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js";

   import "./assets/js/line-chart.js" ;
   import  "./assets/js/pie-chart.js";
   import  "./assets/js/plugins.js";
   import  "./assets/js/scripts.js";

import {  RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <RouterView />
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap or Bootstrap-Vue?

Comment: ok but there several files have same issue.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Also, why do you manually import local files rather than using NPM packages?

Comment: i installed Jquey  by this  `npm install jquery --save-dev` and imported in my app.js file but still same issue .                                                                                                                                             `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jQuery')`

Comment: Let's focus and not mix everything from the beginning. [This may](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73161570/8816585) be a way to make jQuery work in your codebase. Even tho, I'm not sure why you would need jQuery at all since you're using Vue. Can you get rid of it? Then, what do you use Bootstrap, or Bootstrap-Vue? Finally, can you use NPM rather than inline imports? Please give me some feedback on the first point and answer to the other 3 questions in your next comment(s) to it to be efficient debugging-wise.

Comment: thnaks for support. i am new in **vue js** so no idea about this.  another thing is i am not using Jquery. Actually    i have a file with template that is using jquery file.