# Adding jquery to VueJS 3 for Bootstrap 5 compability to use a modal

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Soo, originally I just wanted include a boostrap modal inside a vue component, that I can toggle via an event bus ([mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt)). Clicking outside the modal should not close it and pressing escape shouldn't either. Using the data toggles `<div class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">` should be the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing), but it didn't work. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_backdrop_data&stacked=h) snippet is exactly what I wanted to achieve, but sets the `data-backdrop` inside the button that calls the modal not the modal itself. So I'm already confused. Furthermore when removing the jquery reference in the snippet it breaks. So it seems like I need to import jquery to use bootstrap properly in my vue app. I've installed bootstrap and jquery via npm, but how to import it... [Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928998/how-to-use-a-jquery-plugin-inside-vue) talk about webpack, but I'm not using webpack right now. `<script src=...>` does obviously not work in vue and I can't just import it in the `<script setup>` part. importing it inside `main.js` didn't seem to work either.

Here is my current code for reference (but it shouldn't really matter):

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted, inject, reactive } from 'vue';
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';

const data = reactive({ message: undefined, details: undefined })

let modal;
onMounted(() => {
    modal = new Modal('#errorModal');
})

inject('Events').on('error', function (e) {
    modal.show();
    data.message = e.message;
    data.details = e.details;
})


</script>
<template>
        <div tabindex="-1" id="errorModal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
                        <h4 style="color: white;">Ooops! TODO: DISABLE ABILITY TO CLICK OF MODAL </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                        <p>{{ data.message || 'UNKNOWN_ERROR' }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div v-if="data.details" class="modal-footer">
                        <span class="me-auto">{{ data.details }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- Design from from https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=elegant-error-modal -->
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.modal-confirm {
    color: #434e65;
    width: 525px;
}

.modal-confirm .modal-content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}

.modal-confirm .modal-header {
    background: #e85e6c;
    border-bottom: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -20px -20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    padding: 35px;
}

.modal-confirm h4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.modal-confirm .form-control,
.modal-confirm .btn {
    min-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.modal-confirm .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.modal-confirm .close:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal-confirm .icon-box {
    color: #fff;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 9;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-confirm .icon-box i {
    font-size: 58px;
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
}

.modal-confirm.modal-dialog {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.modal-confirm .btn,
.modal-confirm .btn:active {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #eeb711 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    line-height: normal;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    min-width: 150px;
    border: none;
}

.modal-confirm .btn:hover,
.modal-confirm .btn:focus {
    background: #eda645 !important;
    outline: none;
}

.trigger-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
</style>
```

By the way should I use `import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';`  to interact with bootstrap items anyways? I've seen 50 variants to manipulate them. What's the standard way?

Answer (score 0):

To show or hide a Bootstrap modal with Vue, no need for jQuery, just play on class and style of the .modal element:

- `<div class="modal">...</div>` -> the modal is hidden
- `<div class="modal show" style="display: block;">...</div>` -> the modal is visible

An example with a `showModal` ref (but the trigger could be an event bus, or anything else):

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const showModal = ref(false)
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="showModal = true">Show modal</button>

  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="exampleModal"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
    :class="{ show: showModal }"
    :style="{ 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)', display: showModal ? 'block' : 'none' }"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" @click="showModal = false"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```